# Change to a new directory in Linux, while remembering the current, and cd back to it

Tags: linux, command-line, cd-command

The `pushd` and `popd` are very useful and often needed when working on the command line, but I'm not enjoying them to the extent they can. It is subjective but I find the naming of the pair to be unintuitive.

Are there other commands for temporarily changing a directory and then returning to the original?

Comment: What about `cd dir; cd -` ? pushd popd display unrelevant informations

Comment: By the way, you can actually tell your shell that every cd should be pushing to the directory stack like pushd, and that you can go back by doing things like `cd -1`

Comment: If it's just the naming that's unintuitive, just make an alias or a wrapper function. I don't see the value in a post that's just about making an alias for a specific command. This might at best be a comment on some other post suggesting `pushd`/`popd` as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I really like @gilles answer `cd newdir` to get to a new directory and `cd -` to go back.

If you need to `cd` into a few directories and rollback, adopting the concept of a calculator helps me, and I recommend adding the following two aliases to your bash profile:

```
alias cdm="pushd"    # m is for memorize
alias cdr="popd"     # r is for recall.
```

Now it become intuitive:

```
cdm newdir
```

and do what is needed in `newdir`. To go back to the original directory simply use

```
cdr
```